# How much cash do you lose when you die in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands

When you die in Borderlands, you keep all your items, but lose some cash when you respawn at a New-U station. I can't find a clear answers of what percentage of your cash is lost or if it scales with some other factor as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The amount of money you lose upon death is approximately 7% of the total amount you're currently carrying. While there is some variability on the Internet about what this % is (5%, 7%, 10%, etc.) the top voted answer [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/942810-borderlands/answers?qid=127446) seems trustworthy as the user ran 3 separate tests all in a row.

Comment: Seems right. Also found a confirmation here: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/New-U_Station